# Choropleth Map - visualize data over time

Tags: python, time-series, choropleth

I have data from 2000-2016 that I want to display year by year on a choropleth map. Does anyone have experience doing this in Python, or any recommendations?

I have been working with folium, but haven't been able to figure out how to add the time dimension.